# How to avoid double selection in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, openlayers

We have Vue.js application where we use OpenLayers. We draw some graphical objects and I have an issue with selection. We use OpenLayers' Select and Modify interactions to select and move points-like objects and ol-ext's extension package to move other types of graphical objects such as lines, polygons etc. The issue is when we select points-like objects everything works fine that is there is blue point only, which we use to click and drag them, but when we select non-points-like objects there are both OpenLayers and ol-ext interactions. There should be ol-ext's interaction only. It looks as followings:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the selected polygon has blue OpenLayers' frame and ol-ext's redish frame. We need to have the redish frame only when we select polygons.

The code looks as following:

```
editGeometry (edit) {
  if (!edit) {
    this.modifyNonPoint.un('select', this.onModifyNonPoint)
    this.selectedFeatures.un('add', this.onSelectPoint)
    this.selectedPointFeature.un('change', this.onChangePoint)
    this.devDocMap.removeInteraction(this.modifyNonPoint)
    this.devDocMap.removeInteraction(this.selectPoint)
    this.devDocMap.removeInteraction(this.modifyPoint)
    return
  }
  if (!this.vectorLayer.getSource()) {
    return
  }

  // ol-ext's Transform interaction
  this.modifyNonPoint = new Transform({
    features: this.vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().filter(x => x.get('graphics') && x.get('movable') && !this.isPoint(x))
  })
  this.modifyNonPoint.on('select', this.onModifyNonPoint)
  this.devDocMap.addInteraction(this.modifyNonPoint)

  // OpenLayers' Select interaction
  this.selectPoint = new Select()
  this.selectedFeatures = this.selectPoint.getFeatures()
  this.selectedFeatures.on('add', this.onSelectPoint)
  this.devDocMap.addInteraction(this.selectPoint)

  // OpenLayers' Modify interaction
  this.modifyPoint = new Modify({
    features: this.selectedFeatures
  })
  this.devDocMap.addInteraction(this.modifyPoint)
},
onModifyNonPoint (event) {
  if (event.feature) {
    this.devDocMap.removeInteraction(this.select)
  }
  developedDocumentsApi.saveDrawingGraphics(this.document.id, this.updateGraphicsObjList())
},
onSelectPoint (event) {
  this.selectedPointFeature = event.element
  this.selectedPointFeature.on('change', this.onChangePoint)
},
onChangePoint (event) {
  developedDocumentsApi.saveDrawingGraphics(this.document.id, this.updateGraphicsObjList())
},
isPoint (feature) {
  if (!feature) {
    return false
  }
  const featureGeometry = feature.getGeometry()
  const featureGeometryType = featureGeometry.getType()
  if (featureGeometryType === 'Point') {
    return true
  }
  return false
},
```

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select Points use

```
this.selectPoint = new Select({
  filter: function(feature) { return feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point' }
})
```